# Why is it that in a butterfly network, there is a unique path from the input to the output?

Tags: graphs

Consider the a butterfly network as defined on the following [OCW notes](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/readings/MIT6_042JF10_chap05.pdf) on page 208. An explantation of it can also be found on the [following page](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/project/phrensy/pub/papers/AroraLM94/node7.html).

I was wondering if someone had a proof or an intuition on why there is a unique path from each input to each output on a butterfly network.

Comment: Please provide the required definitions in the question itself.